# NodeJS app don't wait for await on an Microsoft graph client call

Tags: node.js, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

I try to create with NodeJS SDK of Microsoft's Graph API an API call, but graph client seems to finish after my whole app finishes.

```
async function createGroup(url, groupName, accessToken, owner) {

    const authProvider = () => {
        getAccessToken: () => {
            return accessToken;
            }
    };  

    const client = graph.Client.init({
        authProvider
    })


    let data = {
        displayName: groupName,
        mailEnabled: false,
        securityEnabled: true,
        /*"owners@odata.bind": [
            `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/${owner}`
        ]*/
    }
    
    try {
        console.log("start2");
        const resp = await client.api("/groups").post(data);
        console.log("end2");
        return resp
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("demo3")
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
    
}
```

`demo3` or `end2` is never printed to the console.

Comment: is start2 printed? Are there no errors too?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: The Create Group api seems to require a `mailNickname`, but then you would expect to see "demo3".  Does a simple get work: `await client.api('/groups').get()`?

Comment: nope, also not. If I log the result without await I get a `Promise{<pending>}`

Comment: Maybe you should add `await` here: ``` await graph.Client.init....```

Comment: Would you mind editing the post with a code block to indicate how you are calling  `createGroup`?